# Pub/Sub push subscription not forwarding message with schema?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

## Introduction

I've created an Avro Schema which I attached to a Topic. To this Topic I've added two subscriptions, a BigQuery and a Push.

BigQuery Subscription is working great, and the table is appended with the metrics correctly. However I'm having trouble in understanding and decoding Push subscription data.

---

**EDIT** I figured out a detail, what I'm getting is just one of the parameters of my body.

For instance I'm sending this message

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "monitoring_id": "ABLUUUUU",
    "timestamp_micros": 1,
    "updated_rows" : 10,
    "deleted_rows": 0,
    "inserted_rows": 0,
    "bad_formatted_rows": 10
    }
```

I get:

```
{'message': {'attributes': {'googclient_schemaencoding': 'BINARY', 'googclient_schemarevisionid': '404dc06d'}, 'data': 'AhBBQkxVVVVVVQIUAAAU', 'messageId': '7968728425086900', 'message_id': '7968728425086900', 'publishTime': '2023-07-19T13:14:28.08Z', 'publish_time': '2023-07-19T13:14:28.08Z'}, 'subscription': 'projects/proj/subscriptions/metrics'}
```

And when I check my `data`: `AhBBQkxVVVVVVQIUAAAU` which will be `'\x02\x10ABLUUUUU\x02\x14\x00\x00\x14'`.

---

## Problem

The Push PubSub message normally should have this format, according to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push):

```
  {
      "message": {
          "attributes": {
              "key": "value"
          },
          "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
          "messageId": "2070443601311540",
          "message_id": "2070443601311540",
          "publishTime": "2021-02-26T19:13:55.749Z",
          "publish_time": "2021-02-26T19:13:55.749Z"
      },
    "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
  }
```

Where `data` is a base64 of the contents of the message (in the example above, some sort of Hello world!). I was expecting my message to come encoded similarly in base64, but when trying to decode it, it fails to decode as  `utf8`. When I tried other encodings I can have something more "readable" but this shows me that I'm not finding the right message:

### What's happening

My data:

```
"gICAxffntBZIMzUwYzI5NzctZWM3MS00MTM4LWE0NGYtNzFiODAyNjQ3ZDlmkJqLvv20gAYAAAAA"
```

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Decoding with `Node`:

```
> Buffer.from('gICAxffntBZIMzUwYzI5NzctZWM3MS00MTM4LWE0NGYtNzFiODAyNjQ3ZDlmkJqLvv20gAYAAAAA','base64').toString()
'������\x16H350c2977-ec71-4138-a44f-71b802647d9f�������\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

### What I was expecting

What I was expecting:

```
eyJpZCI6IDEyMzUxLCAidGltZXN0YW1wX21pY3JvcyI6IDE2ODk3NjI0MTIzNjEwMDAsICJyb3dzIjogMTB9
```

Which in turn is

```
{'id': 12351, 'timestamp_micros': 1689762412361000, 'rows': 10}
```

## Question

How can I forward the Pub/Sub message, like I did for BigQuery, to an endpoint of my choice? It should be as easy as BigQuery.

Source - Pub/Sub with Schema -> Topic --> Subscriber BigQuery --> End Point Subscriber

## What I've tried

Tried decoding and [checked documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas-valid#subscriber_schema_revisions), because maybe I need to use the avro parser, but I got:

```
avro.errors.InvalidAvroBinaryEncoding: Requested -37 bytes to read, expected positive integer.
```

And my `data` is not base64-y ...

"gICAxffntBZIMzUwYzI5NzctZWM3MS00MTM4LWE0NGYtNzFiODAyNjQ3ZDlmkJqLvv20gAYAAAAA"

## Code

```py
@flask.add_id_to_exceptions()
def create_task(topic_definition : SubscriptionMessage):
    
    logging.info(f"Received topic_definition {topic_definition} from topic")
    
    return "Hello World"
```

Comment: Probably, it may be useful to add your code.

Comment: What is the encoding you have set on your topic? JSON or binary?

Comment: I set the topic to binary.
My code has nothing much special, I only print the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.

The thing is that we need to use AVRO to parse it back from raw bytes:

```
import io
import avro.schema
import avro.io
import base64

def decode_base64_string(base64_string):
    raw_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
    bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)
    decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
    reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
    data = reader.read(decoder)
    return (data)
```